# Viel(es???) Glück

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case, grammar-identification, accusative

I just don't understand the concept here. We have the noun, das Glück. It should be in akusativ form when its used with "viel". And neutral akusativ form for viel is vieles... How come we end up with viel glück?

Comment: Glück is not special in this regard - it's also "viel Wasser", for example.

Comment: Yup, and I would ask the same thing for that too :D I'm trying to understand the concept so I can apply it to other nouns –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keypoint here is that *Glück* is an uncountable noun. If *viel* is followed by an uncountable noun, it is not inflected.

Compare this to the examples [listed on Duden under 1 b)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_zahlreich_vielerlei)

> jemandem viel Vergnügen, viel Glück, viel Spaß wünschen
> viel Arbeit, Geld, Geduld haben
> das kostet viel Zeit, Mühe
> viel Wein trinken
> jemandem mit viel Verständnis, viel Liebe begegnen
> mit viel gutem Willen schaffst du es

This changes however, if you use viel together with an Artikel

> Das viele Glück hat ihm dennoch keinen Reichtum beschert (*even though he was often lucky, he did not become rich afterall*)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand your point for this example but then, there is "vielen Dank" which doesnt follow Artikel neither. Dank here is also an uncountable noun... I'm confused at this point, whats the trick here?

Comment: Okay turns out I had lack of understanding the difference between adverbs and adjectives. All clear now. Thanks again!